# Currency Converter Program

Tags: java, currency

I'm trying to make a program where you can enter an amount in GBP and convert to USD and vice versa. Why is my code wrong? Could you please fix it and tell me why you did what you did.

```
package currencyConverter;

import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ECurrencyConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        currency();
    }

    public static void currency(){
        int choice;  

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What would you like to convert?");
        System.out.println("1. GBP to USD?");
        System.out.println("2. USD to GBP?");

        choice = keyboard.nextInt();

        if(choice == 1){
        float XUSD = (float) 1.64;
            Console console = System.console();
            String input1 = console.readLine("Enter GBP to be converted to USD:");
            float amount1 = input1 * XUSD;
        }else if (choice == 2){
        float XGBP = (float) 0.64;
            Console console = System.console();
            String input2 = console.readline("Enter USD to be converted to GBP:");
            float amount2 = input2 * XGBP;
        }else if (choice > 2 || choice < 1){
            System.out.println("Please pick either option 1 or 2.");
        }
    }       

}
```

Comment: What part of it is "not working"?

Comment: Is your program running? What output you are getting?

Comment: Hello, welcome on Stack Overflow. Here we are using tags to describe technology question is about, so since you already tagged this question with `java` there is no need to repeat this information in title.

Comment: You need to tell *us* what's wrong first. Does it compile? If not, what is the error message and which line it points to? If it compiles, what's the output you get and what did you expect instead?

Comment: Where do you print out the result of your calculation?

Comment: As a side suggestion, **DO NOT** use `float` or `double` for currency calculation (Or their respective wrapper classes). Neither is precise. You can scale it and use `int` or `long`, or you can use Java's `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @hfontanez While that's true in real projects, it's hardly an issue in a homework/practice question like this.

Comment: I know this. I taught Computer Science at a university. But, if you are going to learn, I say learn all the facts.  Besides, my comment was CLEARLY a side note.

Comment: Side note, rather than casting double literals like 1.64 to floats, you can directly assign the float literal by appending an f like `float XUSD = 1.64f;` similarly, you can specify long literals with L, double literals with d, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to switch to a Console - you can continue using your Scanner. Here's a version that works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    currency();
}

public static void currency(){
    int choice;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What would you like to convert?");
    System.out.println("1. GBP to USD?");
    System.out.println("2. USD to GBP?");

    choice = keyboard.nextInt();

    if(choice == 1){
        float XUSD = (float) 1.64;
        System.out.println("Enter GBP to be converted to USD:");
        System.out.println("USD: " + keyboard.nextFloat() * XUSD);
    } else if (choice == 2){
        float XGBP = (float) 0.64;
        System.out.println("Enter USD to be converted to GBP:");
        System.out.println("GBP: " + keyboard.nextFloat() * XGBP);
    } else if (choice > 2 || choice < 1){
        System.out.println("Please pick either option 1 or 2.");
    }
}
```

Moreover, your code should not even compile because you are trying to multiply a `String` by a `float`. You can call `Float.parseFloat(..)` to convert a `String` to a `float`.

Comment: You should make a mention of OP trying to multiply a `float` to a `String`. I'll remove my answer.